# I literally don't know what I need to do for this but it needs to be done and evaluated within a couple of days

Tags: netbeans

1 It's an Emergency.

```
   2 For one of my programming units we have to create a 'UCAS' points calculator in Net beans. UCAS sort out all of the university stuff in the UK.

   3 So I need to create a GUI that has text boxes and buttons and I need to enter the amount of passes, merits, and distinctions I've got on my course, which will give me a total amount of UCAS points.

   4 Passes = 70 points
   5 Merit = 80 points
   6 Distinctions = 90 points

   7 There's 18  units in total, so if I enter I have 4 passes (a pass for 4 units) the box with the total amount of UCAS points needs to go up.

   8 I need three boxes, one for passes, merits, and distinctions, and the box for the total amount of UCAS points. It needs a calculate button of course and a 'reset facility'. It says that the current date needs to be seen on the interface.

   9 It also says that there should be an option to quit the program at any time.

   10 It has to be a **GUI** and I literally don't know what to do and I don't want to fail again.

   11 Can someone help me?

   12 I literally don't know how to make the buttons work or anything.
```

I don't even need any help I just need someone to show me exactly what to do because I haven't got a clue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Please ask your question clearly stating the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Right, so in the UK, UCAS sort out all of the University applications, and they have their own points calculators. On my course, their are 18 units. On each unit you can either get an overall pass, overall merit, or overall distinction. Passes are equal to 70 points, Merits are equal to 80 points, and Distinctions are equal to 90 points. On the GUI I need to create, there needs to be one box for the passes, one for the merits, and for the distinctions. There also needs a box for the total amount of points to add up in.

Comment: So if I get a pass for 6 units, a merit for another 6 units, and a distinction for the other 6, that's 6 x 70, 6 x 80, and 6 x 90. I need to enter in the box for the passes, 6, and the same for the other two, but it needs to add up into the total points box.

Comment: It has to be a GUI though and I literally don't know where to start.

Comment: Not forgetting to mention that current date needs to be displayed and there needs to be a reset button if they enter the wrong number.

Comment: I'm just getting really stressed.